# Как на swift сделать столкновение персонажа?

Tags: xcode, macos, swift3, spritekit

Если есть профессионалы в разработке игр на Swift, а именно на фреймворке SpriteKit, то 
подскажите пожалуйста возможно ли сделать так, что бы персонаж не мог заезжать на слой карты, в данном случае корабль должен врезаться в слой песка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Физику надо наложить НЕ на спрайт, а именно, НА СЛОЙ КАРТЫ, на скриншоте вроде все видно. Спасибо!

Comment: вы может как то гляньте туториалы по обработке коллизий и потом задайте вопросы если что то непонятно?

Comment: Подразумеваю, что можно сделать collision detect, но хотелось бы узнать, возможно ли на карту SKTileMapNode наложить физику, так же как на спрайт SKSpriteNode ?

Comment: Вот тебе статья на тему: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/spritekit-from-scratch-physics-and-collisions--cms-26413

Comment: Нет, статья совсем не на эту тему, я знаю как определить столкнулись ли два спрайта или нет, вопрос в том как вообще столкнуть спрайт с картой (SKTileMapNode)

Answer (score 3):

создаете поле FieldNode, которое воздействует на спрайт при контакте https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skfieldnode

от SKNode "поля" карты будет наследоваться SKFieldNode и к SKFieldNode будет через текстуру создаваться SKPhysicsBody, у SKPhysicsBody с помощью импульса между двумя Node (корабля и "поля") будет взаимодействие с SKPhysicsBody корабля через impulse, подробнее https://habrahabr.ru/post/225517. Создать "поле" проще чем переопрашивать каждый пиксель и его физическое тело с которым по факту и происходит взаимодействие.

Comment: Можно немного по подробней ?

Comment: Можете написать как вы налаживаете физику на карту (SKTileMapNode) ?

Answer (score 2):

Так как каждую клетку (tile) можно использовать с физикой, вам придется проверять 
пользовательские данные для каждой клетки и создавать SKNode для этой клетки, присваивая ей соответствующее физическое тело

[Источник](https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/what-s-new-in-spritekit-on-ios-10-a-look-at-tile-maps/16330/68)

Comment: Смог разобрать каждую клетку, осталось вытащить изображение из клетки дабы по нему наложить физическое тело SKPhysicsBody(texture: ...    в принципе даже и текстуру я достал, но она не подходит tileDefinition?.textures.first  есть идея вытащить имя картинки и по ней попробовать создать текстуру, но что то не могу вытащить имя )

Comment: Можете подсказать как создать для каждой ячейки физику по текстуре этой ячейки ?

Comment: У вас я не думаю что много ячеек в общем и целом, присваивайте соответственно тем, у кого есть "берег".

Comment: Так как хотя бы для одной ячейки создать физику по текстуре этой же ячейки ?

Comment: А вы разве не знаете какая текстура будет у клетки? Это ведь определенный набор текстур, правильно? Или слой генерируется самостоятельно?

Comment: Можете написать как вы налаживаете физику на карту (SKTileMapNode) ?

Comment: Я никак не налаживаю, я сделал поиск и посмотрел как это рекомендуют делать другие, сравнил с вашими и нашел подходящие примеры ;)

Answer (score -4):

Вопрос решен. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var ground : SKTileMapNode!

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.ground = self.childNode(withName: "//ground") as! SKTileMapNode

        let tileSize = self.ground.tileSize

        for col in 0..<self.ground.numberOfColumns {
            for row in 0..<self.ground.numberOfRows {
                let definition = self.ground.tileDefinition(atColumn: col, row: row)

                guard let texture = definition?.textures.first else {
                    continue
                }

                let x = CGFloat(col) * tileSize.width + tileSize.width / 2.0
                let y = CGFloat(row) * tileSize.height + tileSize.height / 2.0

                let tileNode = SKNode()
                tileNode.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
                tileNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: texture, size: texture.size())
                tileNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
                tileNode.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

                self.addChild(tileNode)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В данном примере scaleMode сцены стоит .resizeFill 
Сама сцена и слой карты (self.ground) имеет anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
P.S. Пока это тестовый вариант, потому как еще не известно что же будет при больших картах, ну и думаю надо добавить что бы физика ложилась исключительно на крайние ячейки.

Comment: `Пользователи @gdf1984 и @Daniel Protopopov можете удалить свои ответы, они бесполезны` – вот это довольно грубое заявление. Даже если вы из них не смогли извлечь пользу, другие читатели смогут.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin Почему же грубое, я сказал правду, и никого не обзывал, в чем же здесь грубость ?. Ведь эти ответы действительно не несут никакой полезной информации, их написали просто ради награды ) А вообще если вы видите здесь грубость, то удалите пожалуйста этот вопрос.

Comment: @NickVolynkin я конечно могу, но не буду удалять, действительно, может его сочтёт кто-то ещё полезным. Автор, рад что вы самостоятельно нашли решение.

Comment: @webkostya думаю, вы поторопились с телепатией. Ради чего авторы написали свои ответы — знают только сами авторы.